# multiple add item from viewlist in C#

Tags: c#, listview

I want to select many item from my viewlist and everytime I select an item I , it should add new picturebox, this is my code work for one item and if i select other item the picture changes what should I have add to my code to multiple select.

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            var item = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
            var img = item.ImageList.Images[item.ImageIndex];
            pictureBox1.Image = img;
            selected = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you set [Multiselect](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.multiselect?view=netframework-4.7.2) to true?

Comment: You should be able to do what you want with the comment above and `SelectedItems` property

Comment: Can Someone write the code thank you